# PHP preg cut multiple lines at semi-colon

Tags: php, preg-split

I m blind at preg no matter how many friends trained me, so i wonder if someone could help with the following:

```
SELECT * from tab where a='this is SQL1';
SELECT * FROM tab WHERE a='this is SQL2;
   this is also inside SQL2';
SELECT * FROM tab where a="this is SQL3;
   this is also inside SQL3";
SELECT * from tab where a='this is SQL4;
   this is '' also inside SQL4'
```

I need to convert this text block into an array, cutting at (**;**) -- please note that explode() will not work for this one.

I also do not mind that the **;** have to be the last char at end of a line by using php::trim()

Most cases SQL have to use ', but sometimes also allowed "

The expected result will be:

```
$arr[0] = 'SELECT * from tab where a=\'this is SQL1\'';
$arr[1] = 'SELECT * FROM tab WHERE a=\'this is SQL2;
   this is also inside SQL2\'';
$arr[2] = 'SELECT * FROM tab WHERE a="this is SQL3;
   this is also inside SQL3"';
$arr[3] = 'SELECT * from tab where a=\'this is SQL4;
   this is \'\' also inside SQL4';
```

Comment: Why `ereg`? Why not `explode(';', $text)`?

Comment: Yeah ereg is deprecated (i.e., kaput). explode sounds good. Or preg_split (see http://php.net/preg_split )